# Is there an equivalent of a cage for Blender Internal Render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I see in Cycles, there's the option to use the cage during a bake.

Can you also use it in Blender Internal Render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option to use a custom cage for baking with the Blender internal engine. The closest you can get is the "distance" setting, which will sort of simulate a cage.

From [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html):

> **Select to Active**
>
> Enable information from other objects to be baked onto the active object.
>
> **Distance**
>
> Controls how far a point on another object can be away from the point on the active object. Only needed for Selected to Active. A typical use case is to make a detailed, high poly object, and then bake it’s normals onto an object with a low polygon count. The resulting normal map can then be applied to make the low poly object look more detailed.

Comment: Usally the Distance is setted 0.000; What do you think could be a fair number? I know it dipends on the mesh, but only an advice please. Thank you for the answer

Comment: That distance is in Blender units, so it entirely depends on the scale of your scene. I would start at about 10% of whatever your model's dimensions are, and adjust from there.